# Find min, max, and average of a list

Tags: python, list, max, min

I am having hard time to figure out how to find min from a list
for example

```
somelist = [1,12,2,53,23,6,17]
```

how can I find min and max of this list with defining (`def`) a function

I do not want to use built-in function `min`

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
from __future__ import division

somelist =  [1,12,2,53,23,6,17] 
max_value = max(somelist)
min_value = min(somelist)
avg_value = 0 if len(somelist) == 0 else sum(somelist)/len(somelist)
```

If you want to manually find the minimum as a function:

```
somelist =  [1,12,2,53,23,6,17] 

def my_min_function(somelist):
    min_value = None
    for value in somelist:
        if not min_value:
            min_value = value
        elif value < min_value:
            min_value = value
    return min_value
```

Python 3.4 introduced the [`statistics`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) package, which provides `mean` and additional stats:

```
from statistics import mean, median

somelist =  [1,12,2,53,23,6,17]
avg_value = mean(somelist)
median_value = median(somelist)
```

Comment: would like to point out that that average value is susceptible to division by 0 errors.

Comment: yes, but I want to find like in array list. What I mean by that is set for min = array[0] then, for i in array, if i =< 0 print min, I need to know how can find min and max this way, I tried but it doesn't work, not sure why

Comment: I'm not sure what you want.  Do you want the index of the minimum value?

Comment: def FindMinimum(array):
        #write your code here
        return minimum

def FindMaximum(array):
        #write your code here
        return maximum

def FindAverage(array):
        #write your code here
        return average

list = [2,4,6,8,1,3,5,7]
print "min: ", FindMinimum(list)
print "max: ", FindMaximum(list)
print "average: ", FindAverage(list)                                    I think this is the one of the example had on codecademy.com i am trying to figure this out at the moment, if you can help me with this I will appreciate so much, Thank you

Comment: Why don't you look into searching/sorting/finding min max/ algorithm. You will get more efficient answers in that community

Comment: I think it's best if you figure it out and write it yourself.  If you have problems understanding please ask.

Comment: So 4 x list traversals to get all of those values... Shouldn't there be a one liner for this stuff in python?

Comment: In order to minimize number of comparisons, it is best to proceed in pairs: if a[2k] < a[2k+1]: (if a[2k] < min: min=a[2k]; if max < a[2k+1]: max=a[2k+1]) else:  (if a[2k+1] < min: min=a[2k+1]; if max < a[2k]: max=a[2k]) which amounts to 3n/2 comparisons instead of the 2n for the naive implementation; maybe some labda-wizzard can turn that ino a one-liner in python.

Comment: What for is "from __future__ import division'" there at the top of the code?

Comment: back in 2014 python 2.7 was in common use.  The division operator functionality was changed from python 2 to 3, and using `from __future__ import division` essentially imported the python 3 division operator, overriding the python 2 operator functionality.

Answer (score 5):

Return min and max value in tuple:

```
def side_values(num_list):
    results_list = sorted(num_list)
    return results_list[0], results_list[-1]


somelist = side_values([1,12,2,53,23,6,17])
print(somelist)
```

Comment: This is the best way to find the min/max using built-ins.  Sorting is O(nlogn), getting min/max is O(1)

Comment: @Baldrick: Actually, min() and max() are O(n). So, sorting is slower.

Comment: @Hinni after sorting min is at index `0` and max is at index `length` (or vice versa). Once sorted there is no need to use `min()` or `max()` to find those values.

Comment: Sorry, but now I am in a confused state, so which one is better in term of time consumption, between using 'sorted()' or 'min()' and 'max()'?

Answer (score 3):

Only a teacher would ask you to do something silly like this.
You could provide an expected answer. Or a unique solution, while the rest of the class will be (yawn) the same...

```
from operator import lt, gt
def ultimate (l,op,c=1,u=0):
    try:
        if op(l[c],l[u]): 
            u = c
        c += 1
        return ultimate(l,op,c,u)
    except IndexError:
        return l[u]
def minimum (l):
    return ultimate(l,lt)
def maximum (l):
    return ultimate(l,gt)
```

The solution is simple. Use this to set yourself apart from obvious choices.

Answer (score 0):

```
list=[]
n = int(input("Enter the length of your list: "))
for i in range (1,n+1):
    a=int(input("Enter the %d number: " %i ))
    list.append(a)
min=list[0]
max=list[0]
for i in range(1,n):
    if max<list[i]:
        max=list[i]
    if min>list[i]:
        min=list[i]
print(" %d is the biggest number " %max)
print(" %d is the smallest number " %min)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your list : `somelist = [1,12,2,53,23,6,17]`, first, make it a DataFrame using Pandas.
Then you can use the `describe()` method on the DF.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
somelist = [1,12,2,53,23,6,17]
somelist_df = pd.DataFrame(somelist)
somelist_df.describe()
```

OUTPUT:

```
count   7.000000
mean    16.285714
std 18.052833
min 1.000000
25% 4.000000
50% 12.000000
75% 20.000000
max 53.000000
```