# How would i go about getting the total to show the actual total?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
i = 0
integers = []
total = 0
while i < 10:
num = input('Enter an integer: ')
    try:
        integers.append(int(num))
        i = i + 1
    except:
        print('Bad input')
for i in integers:
    total = total + 1
average = total / 10
print('this is the list of integers you entered: ',(integers))
print('The lowest number is: ',min(integers))
print('The highest number is: ',max(integers))
print('This is the average of all integers: ',(average))
sorted_list = sorted(integers)
print('The integers list sorted in ascending sequence: ',(sorted_list))
sorted_list.reverse()
print('The  integers list sorted in descending sequence: ',(sorted_list))
```

currently the total is equal to however many integers i enter i understand its from 
    total = total + 1 how would i go about getting the total to be the total of all integers entered?

Comment: `total=total+i`

Comment: By the way https://stackoverflow.com/q/27009247/2308683

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do

```
total = total + i
```

and check the indentation in the line

```
num = input('Enter an integer: ')
```

it should be one level indside

Comment: wow that fixed it thank you and the indentation was just me being new to this sight so i probably just messed it up

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop. Python has a sum function

```
total = sum(integers)
```