# Is there a more effective way of finding the min/max/sum of a list without having to create another variable to find the sum

Tags: python

For example I couldn't figure out how to find the minimum value in the list called "cars" by simply printing out print min(cars) however making variable called X worked

```py
cars = range (1,101)
x = sum(cars)
print( x)
```

Comment: `print(min(cars))` is completely valid Python here.

Comment: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Ran the same code on my machine, output was 5050 (correct sum).
Further more, simply running `print(sum(range(1, 101)))` works just fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find min, max, and average of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27009247/find-min-max-and-average-of-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

In python you can use the built-in functions `max`,`min` or `sum` to print the value of each method.
There is not need to assign it to a variable.
For instance, doing `print(max([1,2,3,4]))` will print 4